# cacerts.bks does not exist

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, keytool, sniffing

I have rooted my Android (4.0.4) phone and installed an app which proxies all HTTP traffic through my computer. This works fine and I can see and modify all HTTP requests. But HTTPS-traffic does not pass through. I have exported the certificate of my proxy but I found out that there is no `cacert.bks`-file in the `/system/etc/security`-folder.

So how can I add my custom certificate to the list of trusted certificates using `keytool`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the issue with a self signed webserver certificate which I could not install by just open it.
I've got a "CertInstaller(28614): didn't find matched private key" in logcat.
My solution:

If you want to install new certificates into the android system cacert store when it does not use the bks file anymore:

You have to have root of course.

1. You have to get the certificate (export from browser) as pem format.
   PEM is a encoded format like:

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDtjCCAp6gAwIBAgIQRJmNPMADJ72cdpW56tustTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB1
> ...
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```

2. You have to get the hash for the subject name.

   > openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -in yourcert.crt

You will get something like 0d188d89 back.

3. You have to get the text version of the certificate.

   > openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in yourcert.crt > yourcert.txt
4. You have to switch the text and the pem section within a editor.
   It should look like this:

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDtjCCAp6gAwIBAgIQRJmNPMADJ72cdpW56tustTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB1
> ...
> -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
> Certificate:
>     Data:
>         Version: 1 (0x0)
>         Serial Number:
> ...
> ```

5. You rename the file to "0d188d89.0"
6. Copy the file with adb or something else to /system/etc/security/cacerts/.

You can check by just going into settings / security / trusted credentials / system
The certs are sorted by the "Organization" field from the certs.

Information used from: http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer saved my day :)
Here a small addendum: if you use openssl version >= 1.0, then you have to use `-subject_hash_old` instead of `-subject_hash`

Comment: You should add `-noout` to your `openssl` command, which will eliminate the need for step 4.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, you dont have to root your device to install your trusted certificates after ICS. There is setting for that.

http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649774

Comment: Correct, you can simply put it on the SD card and import from Settings. If you are interested in how the trust store works on ICS+, some details here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html. In short, certs you add end up in `/data/misc/keychainca/certs-added`.

Comment: That seems to work for a couple of programs, but not the app which I wanted to sniff the traffic of.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the use of an oder openssl (0.9.*) on android, I had to use "-subject_hash_old" instead of -subject_hash" in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18390177/3043726 of user user2708846 here.

I've summarized the steps I took (including changing file permissions, copying the file to the android device, and help on how to verify that the certificates are installed correctly) at the cyanogenmod forum http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/82875-installing-cacert-certificates-on-android-as-system-credentials-without-lockscreen/
and on my own blog http://wiki.pcprobleemloos.nl/android/